# Safari cannot open the page because the address in invalid

Tags: ios, swift, safari, ios-simulator

My app sends the user to Safari to open a URL with this:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

This works fine with urls I've obtained from TMDB but when I get podcast URLs from queries to http://itunes.apple.com/search?media=podcast&lang=en_us&term=1468013270 I take the `collectionViewUrl` field from the JSON response and try to send the user there. In the iOS Simulator I get that Safari error message. If I cut and paste the `CollectionViewUrl` into an actual Safari tab I go to the web page. And if I test this on my actual iPhone I get sent to the podcast app where this show is pulled up. I'm just wondering why the simulator gives this response?

Comment: Probably because the simulator doesn't have the needed app installed. It works on a real device, that's what is important. There's lots of things that can't be done in the simulator.

Comment: I guess you are right if that URL somehow tells Safari to switch to the podcast app, then I agree that the podcast app is likely not installed in the iOS Simulator. I just didn't know a regular http:// in a Safari tab would do that....

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to disable "Block all Cookies" feature on the safari settings?

it worked for me

[image: See Attached]